# Exception in Ignite-Kubernetes integration

Tags: kubernetes, ignite

I am new to Ignite and Kubernetes.

Trying to integrate Ignite Version 2.6.0 data grid application in AKS.
Client jar file is in VM, where kubectl is exposed. Using kubectl executed all .yaml files, in the client jar VM, as per the below url

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/stateful-deployment

Able to telnet master url of the Kubernetes cluster from the VM where Client jar is present.

ignite-stateful-set.yaml is configured with ‘example-kube-persistence.xml’ as mentioned below.
- name: selfLink
          value: file:///opt/example-kube-persistence.xml

Ignite client is reading the configuration like ...
try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/examples/config/example-ignite.xml"))

**example-ignite.xml configuration ...**

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder">
                <property name="namespace" value="ignite"/>
                <property name="serviceName" value="ignite"/>

                                   <property name="masterUrl" value="https://xxxxxxxxx.azmk8s.io:443"/>
                                   <property name="AccountToken" value="/data/ignite"/>

                </bean>
```

**Started running client and getting the following exception...**

```
 class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to retrieve Ignite pods IP addresses.
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.getRegisteredAddresses(TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.java:172)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.registeredAddresses(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1828)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.resolvedAddresses(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1776)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.sendJoinRequestMessage(ServerImpl.java:1029)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.joinTopology(ServerImpl.java:890)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.spiStart(ServerImpl.java:373)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.spiStart(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1948)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:297)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:915)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1721)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1028)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2014)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1723)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1151)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:1069)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:955)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:854)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:724)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:693)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:352)
    at com.ecoenergy.cortix.ignite.IgniteFutureAsync.main(IgniteFutureAsync.java:54)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to load services account token [setAccountToken= /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.serviceAccountToken(TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.java:287)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.getRegisteredAddresses(TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.java:148)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Files.java:3152)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.serviceAccountToken(TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.java:285)
    ... 21 more
```

Please help me out how to get rid of exception. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for the service account token in `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token` but that file does not exist. The question is why?

Some commands:

```
kubectl get serviceaccounts
```

You should find one called "ignite". If not, that's your problem.

```
kubectl get serviceaccounts/ignite -o yaml
```

If there's a property called `automountServiceAccountToken` set to `false` that's your problem.

At the bottom it should list the secrets. If not, that's your problem.

```
kubectl get secrets/default-token-wnfp5 -o yaml
```

(Obviously replace with your secret name.)

You should find a token in the output.

```
kubectl get pods
kubectl get pods/ignite-0 -o yaml
```

You're looking for the local name of the secret. And then, later in the file, where it's mounted. If it's not mounted, that's your problem. If it's pointing somewhere weird, that's your problem.

Also, have a look at:

```
kubectl get clusterrolebinding/ignite
```

The roleref and subjects should all point to sensible values.

Kubernetes has so many levels of indirections that it's easy to miss a link somewhere. If you didn't accidentally miss a step (or there are some Azure quirks) you can also look at the [service account documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/).

Comment: Changing to lower case didn't worked out.  
I need to check more on the RBAC enabling on AKS?  - as client is  trying to lookup for token.  
Is there any way to check this path in cluster using kubectl.

Comment: is my cache configuration is better to maintain in example-default.xml (read by client jar) or   
in example-kube-persistence.xml (configured in ignite-stateful-set.yaml)?

Comment: Did you follow the steps in the Azure deployment guide? (https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/microsoft-azure-deployment) As you say, probably something to do with creating the service account.

Comment: You probably want to open another question about where to put cache config; it has a much wider audience that K8s on Azure. (In short: doesn't matter.)

Comment: Is there any way to get accountToken path from kubectl? As I mentioned client is in VM, we need to get the path of accountToken using something like kubectl, and place it in a VM path where client is referencing and it matches to that of in Kubernetes?
Please let me know if my understanding is correct. What is the file format extension of this token file? If any sample file please post.

Comment: As of now I am deleting/creating ignite-stateful-set.yaml for all configuration changes. I hope there is no need to delete other yaml files of RBAC, if I change ignite-stateful-set.yaml.

Comment: As this is a stateful deployment, I create only ignite-stateful-set.yaml and which is configured with - name: selfLink value: file:///opt/example-kube-persistence.xml. RBAC and Ignite-service yaml files are also created. Stateless yaml files are not created. 

Following are the files created as per https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/stateful-deployment

* ignite-account-role.yaml (RBAC)
* ignite-namespace.yaml  (RBAC)
* ignite-role-binding.yaml  (RBAC)
* ignite-service-account.yaml  (RBAC)
* ignite-service-account.yaml (Ignite-service)
* ignite-stateful-set.yaml (stateful deployment)